# Embedded backgorund image in SSRS report placement problem

Tags: ssrs-2008

I need to place an embedded background image (this is bmp file with just a text) on a specific location in the report. Like at the center of the report. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to prepare the image such that it would fit in the specific position in the report.